# Page_Load of control firing twice, tried known resolutions

Tags: vb.net

I am upgrading a 1.1 web app to 4.0 and am running into an issue with the page_load of a custom user control firing twice, both being treated as non-postbacks (IsPostBack is false in the case). I have read around and it seems that there are 2 culprits to this, 1 being an img tag without something in the src part (which there are no images on this page at all) or 2 an issue with AutoEventWireup and Handles being used at the same time. I have looked through all my code and there are no Handles keywords in there at all and AutoEventWireUp is set to true on every page, yet I still get this issue. Here is some source

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If Not IsPostBack Then
    End If
End Sub
```

And the declaration

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" CodeBehind="UCHeader.ascx.vb" Inherits="PO.Web.UCHeader"
AutoEventWireup="true" TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" %>
```

I can show more source if needed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest setting AutoEventWireup = false. Read this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814745) since the aspx framework calls methods based on their method name/signature and the autoeventwireup is generating code to bind the events they are being called twice. At least that was the behavior in prior versions of .net/visual studio I haven't found anything that states whether that is the case in visual studio 2010.

Comment: Setting AutoEventWireup = false garners the same issue. Would there be a project setting that would cause this? I copy/pasted the code that isn't working into a new 4.0 project and am not having the same issue.

Comment: Did the new project have the AutoEventWireup set to false? If that is the case my only assumption is that the events were already wired up in the code behind and you would have to go in and manually remove the code that wires up the events even with the AutoEventWireup set to false it wouldn't actually remove the code.

Comment: If you mean the "Handles" Keyword, I have removed all of them. Is there more that needs to get taken out?

Comment: You could look in the designer.vb file. So the second project you created worked? What value did you have set for the AutoEventWireup property?